# fragmentManager() and findFragmentById() type Casting

Tags: java, android

i am embading GoogleMaps in to My android app..everything working Rights but id don't know that when we use `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);` to typecast it to `MapFragment` tell my that we are typecasting the return type of `getFragmentManager()` or `findFragmentById()` Method my code is as bellow

```
mapFrag =  (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();
```

Comment: try using `SupportMapFragment ` and `getSupportFragmentManager `

Comment: its working fine but i want to know that how to typecast to MapFragment .. its the getFragmentManager is typcasting or findFragmentByid() return type is typecasted..

Comment: i am not sure if i understood you're question right but you are type casting `findFragmentById(R.id.map)` into `MapFragment`

Comment: then what is the meaning of getFragmentManager() Method i can write directly findFragmentById() but it gives me an error